# Animation does not work properly in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated

I tried making a carousel by watching a tutorial but I cannot get it to work for an event driven animation. Instead of animating it just updates the position to new location.

This does not happen if I use only one type of animation for transition, mentioning just one value to transform rotate instead of passing an expression.

[what it looks like](https://i.imgur.com/qbLQpew.mp4)

[what it should look like](https://i.imgur.com/LFljF03.mp4)

```
const cards = ["tomato", "teal", "pink"]
const alpha = Math.PI/6

const Trans = () => {
const value = React.useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current
const [toggled, setToggled] = React.useState(false)

const animationFn = () => {
    Animated.spring(value, {
        toValue: 1,
        friction: 10,
        useNativeDriver: true
    }).start()
    setToggled(toggled => !toggled)
}

const rotateOpen = (rotate) => {
    return value.interpolate({       
        inputRange: [0, 1],
        outputRange: ['0rad', `${rotate}rad`]
    })
}

const rotateClose = (rotate, maxValues) => {
    return value.interpolate({       
        inputRange: [0, 1],
        outputRange: [`${maxValues}rad`, `${rotate}rad`]
    })
}

return(
    <>
    {cards.map((card, index) => {
        const rotate = toggled ? (index - 1) * alpha : 0
        const maxValues = (index-1) * alpha
        return (
            <Animated.View key={card} style={{transform: [
                {translateY: -50},
                {translateX: -100},                 
                {rotate: !toggled ? rotateOpen(rotate) : rotateClose(rotate, maxValues) },                        
                {translateX: 100},                  
            ], borderRadius: 15, position: 'absolute', backgroundColor: card, height: 100, width: 200}} />
        )
    })}

  
    <View style={{paddingTop: 100}}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { animationFn() }}>
        <Text style={{fontSize: 30}}>  Animate </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
    </>
)
}
```

Comment: show how you want the animation look like...

Comment: Could you output the calculated value of rotate: to your consol.log to see what its true value is - what happens if index==0 for example? And you could set the value in a variable currot = !toggled ? rotateOpen(rotate) : rotateClose(rotate, maxValues) and then use that variable in rotate:  currot to see what happens. Are  you seeing any errors on the console?

Comment: the values are correct, its just that the animations are not happening and its just updating to the final state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your interpolation values shouldn't change between the open and close functions. The animation library knows that when you go from 0 to 1, you're rotating the block "out" and then when you go from 1 back to 0, you're applying the same interpolation in reverse

so this code appears to work correctly for me:

```
const Trans = () => {
  const value = React.useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
  const [toggled, setToggled] = React.useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    Animated.spring(value, {
      toValue: toggled ? 0 : 1,
      friction: 10,
      useNativeDriver: false,
    }).start();
  }, [toggled, value]);

  return (
    <>
      {cards.map((card, index) => {
        const rotate = (index - 1) * alpha;

        return (
          <Animated.View
            key={card}
            style={{
              transform: [
                { translateY: -50 },
                { translateX: -100 },
                {
                  rotate: value.interpolate({
                    inputRange: [0, 1],
                    outputRange: ['0rad', `${rotate}rad`],
                  }),
                },
                { translateX: 100 },
              ],
              borderRadius: 15,
              position: 'absolute',
              backgroundColor: card,
              height: 100,
              width: 200,
            }}
          />
        );
      })}

      <View style={{ paddingTop: 100 }}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {
            setToggled(!toggled);
          }}>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 30 }}> Animate </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </>
  );
};
```